# MySQL updating sort_order fields with unique constraints causes unique constraint violation

Tags: mysql, sorting, duplicates, constraints, unique

I have this table structure:

Table1: `id, group_id, label, sort_order`

Keys: `PK: id, UNIQUE: group_id+sort_order, INDEX: group_id`

Sample data:

```
id   group_id   label       sort_order
50   1          Field 1     1 
51   1          Field 2     2
52   1          Field 3     3
```

Where `(group_id, sort_order)` is a unique key.

To update the arrangement of records on front-end, the `sort_order` field is used in order by clause. User can update the order by dragging labels around in front-end, which passes the ids, ex: `52, 51,50` which is then treated as the new order/sorting.

Expected result:

```
id   group_id   label       sort_order
50   1          Field 1     3 
51   1          Field 2     2
52   1          Field 3     1
```

The process should update all 3 records with the new `sort_order` values. Sample update query:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET sort_order = 1 WHERE id = 52 AND group_id = 1
```

However, since sort_order is part of a unique key, it throws error since `group_id,sort_order` key already exists.

I did a hackish workaround where I update the sort order twice, ex: by updating it into a higher value, ex: `sort_order = actual_order + 1000` then update again using the actual values, ex: `sort_order = actual_order`.

What would be the better approach? Should I just remove the unique key completely instead?

--

EDIT

--

To give a better view of the problem, here is my PHP code:

Sample fieldIds: `52,51,50` or `50,51,52` or `51,52,50`. The sequence determines the new sorting.

```
public function updateSort($projectId, $groupId, $subgroupId, array $fieldIds)
{
    // Other stuff
    // ...

    $statement = create_a_prepared_statement(); // ...

    // Updating sort_order directly would result to unique key violation
    // so change the sort_order into some negative numbers and re-sort with
    // the actual orders
    foreach ($fieldIds as $sortIndex => $fieldId) {
        $sort = $sortIndex - 1000;
        $statement->execute(array(
            'id' => $fieldId,
            'project_id' => $projectId,
            'group_id' => $groupId,
            'subgroup_id' => $subgroupId,
            ':0' => $sort,
        ));
    }

    // Now sort it correctly
    foreach ($fieldIds as $sortIndex => $fieldId) {
        $sort = $sortIndex + 1;
        $statement->execute(array(
            'id' => $fieldId,
            'project_id' => $projectId,
            'group_id' => $groupId,
            'subgroup_id' => $subgroupId,
            ':0' => $sort,
        ));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you can't move the sort_order out of the PK and put the actual unique id in there?

Comment: Your hack is a reasonable approach.  I typically use negative values, so they are immediately obvious if something goes wrong.  Another possibility is to use `NULL` values.

Comment: @MutuYolbulan . . . The OP stated that the combination is a *unique* key, not a *primary key*.  I would guess that `id` is the primary key.

Comment: @MutuYolbulan group_id+sort_order is an additional unique key aside from the autoincrement id. Updated question to add the keys detail.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll try to use negative values then. Seems reasonable.

Comment: if you have to have group and sort as unique, your hack would be the only way to do it unless you remove the entire constraint before the update and then put it back, which I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: @MutuYolbulan - we are expecting less than 10 records per group, currently max 3 fields in a group. I think I'll stick with the hackish way for now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Considering what you wrote in this statement:

```
I did a hackish workaround where ...
```

I would perform the first half of that phrase,

```
sort_order = actual_order + 1000
```

and then **stop** (meaning you are done).

You will never in 100 years experience an overflow on the max value. If that is of concern, have your annual event (via Create Event) remind you how far from concern it is, and reign that group back to 1+, when it is.

But you would need to update any given group **2M** times for an overflow.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. See my edit with sample PHP codes. Although that would still result to duplicate since the actual order always starts with `1`, ex: `1,2,3`. Maybe the next time I sort, I'll have it in negative values, then on next sort, positive values. I don't know, but this might be useful enhancement to my current codes. Thanks

Comment: will happily run it thru PHP and help figure it out in the morning or sooner. Kinda enjoying the football game :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have such a strict constraint, you will have to use an intermediate value:

```
 UPDATE Table1 SET sort_order = -1 WHERE id = 52 AND group_id = 1;
 UPDATE Table1 SET sort_order =  3 WHERE id = 50 AND group_id = 1;
 UPDATE Table1 SET sort_order =  1 WHERE id = 52 AND group_id = 1;
```

`-1` is the intermediate value.

The whole process:

- Place sort_order for given group for record 1 at intermediate value;
- Place sort_order of record 2 to desired value;
- Place sort_order of record 1 to desired value;

So to keep the constraint you will always have to update 2 records, and 1 record even 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

after 7 years from your question, why don't you just drop the composite unique constraint on sort_order?

Answer (score 0):

As you have made sort_order a unique key, So you can't store same value multiple times. When table have no data then insert can be perform easily. But in your case as data already exist in table and you need to change the order value. It will work exactly **swapping** of data. For example you have 3 glasses of milk, water and tea and you need to swap them. Than you need a 4th glass or each time you need empty glasses. Similarly, to store data like this

- first you need to delete the records than insert again or
- You can make 1 field empty(make sure no field also has empty value) than swap one by one

Or simply you can remove the unique key from sort_order

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of it, your front end is generating update statements that update one row at a time.  If at any time an update statement causes 2 rows to have the same values a unique key violation will result.  I think you should look into finding a way to update all rows with sort values in one statement.  I'm not familiar with mysql but I am familiar with sql server.  In sql server I would copy the table to a temp table and figure out the new sorting there.  Then perform a update statement to copy the new sort values back to the original table in one statement.

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL. In MySQL even a temporary uniqueness violation will fail as it is checked row by row not end of statement

Answer (score -2):

You can use a case statement to update all at once

```
UPDATE Table1 set sort_order =
CASE 
WHEN id = 50 THEN 3
WHEN id = 51 THEN 1
WHEN id = 52 THEN 2
END
```

Comment: I updated my code with this type of statement, but mysql still thought I was violating the key.  I wish this worked...I like having a single statement.

Comment: Side note: `CASE` **expression**, not statement. SQL knows no flow control statements at all.

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL. In MySQL even a temporary uniqueness violation will fail as it is checked row by row not end of statement